# Create SQL table from DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I have an unbound datagridview that the user enters information into. When they click save I'd like it to create a new table (not add to an existing table) in the database. Is this possible? The table name would come from textbox text. I'm using SQLCe 3.5

Comment: It's possible.  You would have to make sure the name is not already taken of course.  However, it sounds like a horrible idea.

Comment: I've read a few forums that say the same. Why?

Comment: Since you are willing to read, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Shall the user enter database definition data like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111487/create-an-mysql-alter-table-statement-from-a-datagridview-with-fields-and-option/24116710#24116710) or data from which you try to infer the table? The former is doable, the latter seems crazy since you could not possibly make proper use of the DB's many features..

Comment: The database definition is already entered (by this I assume you mean adding of columns and datatypes etc?) I want it to insert a complete new table into the database, which can then be viewed as a datagridview (on another form, not relevant at the moment) and also be able to view the names of tables in a "server explorer" style function on another form.